# Plot a cube of 3D intensity data

Tags: python, plot, cube

I have k cubes of `(n,n,n)` intensity values and I would like to plot them.

I consider them as diffusion tensors in diffusion MRI and I would like to visualize them (maybe as ellipsoids) and then try to "align" in some way. At present I simply plot for each cube its n "slice" `(n,n)`.

Is there any python module for this task?

Comment: It's not clear where the extra information for the "ellipsoids" would come from. For each tuple `(x,y,z)` you presumably have a scalar value `v` associated with it. To place an ellipsoid at that point you would need four more points of data, two angular values and the length of the major and minor axes.

Comment: I think your "cubes" are the three Eigenvalues of the corresponding diffusion tensor. Do you like to draw an Ellipsoid with its semi-axes lengths corresponding to those three Eigenvalues? By which criterion would you like to align those ellipsoids?

Comment: Each cube represents a sort of tissue voxel, therefore for correct comparison between them, I need to align them. For each cube I think I should compute its diffusion tensor and rotate it wrt the principal axes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use mayavi2 for this. Since I don't have a representation of your data, I gave a minimal working example with some random spheres over a grid below:

```
import numpy
import mayavi.mlab as mlab

# Create some random data
N = 20
x, y, z = numpy.mgrid[-5:5:20j, -5:5:20j, -5:5:20j]
val = numpy.random.random(z.shape)

# Plot and show in mayavi2
pts = mlab.points3d(x, y, z, val, scale_factor=.5,transparent=True)
mlab.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works! (with enthought.mayavi, not simply mayavi)

Comment: The difference between `enthought.mayavi` and `mayavi` is simply how you installed the `mayavi` library in the first place. The former being from the Enthought distribution.